# KendoUI Autocomplete paging issue

Tags: autocomplete, kendo-ui

I have a textbox bound to KendoUI autocomplete widget. The JS code looks like this:

```
        var dataSourceImeSearch = {
            type: "json",
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "@Url.Action("ImeSearch")",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    type: "POST"
                },
                parameterMap: function (data, type) {
                    if (type == "read") {

                        if (data.filter) {
                            data = $.extend({ sort: null, filter: data.filter.filters[0] }, data);
                        } else {
                            data = $.extend({ sort: null, filter: null }, data);
                        }

                        return JSON.stringify(data);
                    } else {
                        return JSON.stringify({ model: data });
                    }
                }
            },
            batch: false,
            pageSize: 10,
            serverPaging: true,
            serverFiltering: true,
            serverSorting: true,
            schema: {
                errors: "Errors",
                data: "Data",
                total: "TotalRecordCount",
                model: myModel
            },
            error: function (e) {
                if (e.errors) {
                    alert(e.errors);
                }
            }
        };

        $("#Ime").kendoAutoComplete({
            dataTextField: "PunoIme",
            filter: "contains",
            minLength: 3,
            dataSource: dataSourceImeSearch
        });
```

I am experiencing a weird thing here. Autocomplete is working in terms that when I type the third character it runs to the server and gets JSON data back from there and shows first ten results. The thing is that this textbox is searching large datasets, so for some queries with say 4 characters result set can be more than 1000 items. For some reason the widget is not figuring out that there are more than 10 results and when I scroll down in the autocomplete dropdown which gets shown, it will not fire any search for a second page and so on. You can see that the `serverPaging` for data source is set to `true`, but this does not help.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I found out after posting this question that Autocomplete widget does not allow paging by design. This was explained in the KendoUI forums by some Kendo employee as an example of poor UX (if you have autocomplete that needs paging). I would argue that, since in my opinion, the first use case of the autocomplete would be in case of a search of a person, and here I am doing exactly that. The only problem is that if you search by person's second name you can end up with hundreds of results after first 3 or 4 characters and you really need paging for that. If the Kendo people think that this is a case of a bad UX, this should be clearly mentioned in the Autocomplete documentation, and I could really not find any mentioning of it at a single place, and one would think that it might be a good idea to mention something like this to the people so that they don't have to waste all day trying to figure out what went wrong.

In my opinion one of the worst use case examples at all demos at KendoUI web demo pages is the [Shared DataSource](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/datasource/shared-datasource.html) example, where if you type in 'ch' in the autocomplete textbox in the top, you will end up with 10 results in autocomplete, but 14 in the datagrid bellow. It really strikes me as stupid that nobody in Kendo sees this behavior as odd.

So my answer to my own question would be the following: DO NOT use autocomplete, except in some really really simple use case (I can't really think of a single one that would make sense). I ended up making a whole search form with 5 textboxes and search button in case where I hoped that I was going to be able to use 2 textboxes (one with autocomplete) and a search button.

Comment: I agree, there are cases where you might want a 'show more results' option at the bottom of the list. Whether it is good UX or not is a matter of opinion, it seems a bit arrogant of Kendo to omit support for it based on their opinion. An alternative you could look at is Select2, it does support 'infinite scrolling', as they call it http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#infinite

Answer (score 0):

You have set pageSize:10, which means that only 10 records are returned to the AutoComplete and its dataSource contains only 10 elements, I am afraid that automatic paging is not implemented by default